# 3d Acceleration VMware drag mouse issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, vmware

I'm able to run Unity programs on my virtual machine, only dragging with the mouse doesn't work. Anyone who has an idea how to enable this feature?

I have installed VMware Tools and 3D Acceleration is enabled, cause I can start the program. Only drag features with the mouse doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution: Under general mouse and keyboard settings set Gaming to "Always optimize mouse for games" . So VMware  options -> keyboard + mouse settings, edit the profile, then click on  the General tab.